# Recreate D3 Multi-Line Chart on Resize (responsive)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In order to have a responsive D3 multi-line chart I have added a resize function but it doesn't seem to work although the function gets called:

```js
  var data = [{
    Date: "2016-10-10",
    ValueOne: 1,
    ValueTwo: 0
  }, {
    Date: "2016-10-17",
    ValueOne: 23,
    ValueTwo: 2
  }, {
    Date: "2016-10-24",
    ValueOne: 32,
    ValueTwo: 17
  }, {
    Date: "2016-10-31",
    ValueOne: 57,
    ValueTwo: 40
  }, {
    Date: "2016-11-07",
    ValueOne: 74,
    ValueTwo: 56
  }];


var  margin = {top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 50},
// Set default width and height
    widther = (window.innerWidth),
    width = widther - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    
// Determine current size, which determines vars
function set_vars() {

    var width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
}

function drawGraphic() {

    var svg = d3.select('#charts')
      .append('svg')
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //Parses date for correct time format
    var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Date = new Date(d.Date)
    });

    var valueOneData = data.map(function(d) {
      return {
        date: d.Date,
        value: d.ValueOne
      }
    });

    var valueTwoData = data.map(function(d) {
      return {
        date: d.Date,
        value: d.ValueTwo
      }
    });

    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.Date
      }));

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0])
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.ValueOne
      }) * 1.05]);

    var lineGenerator = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.date)
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value)
      });

    var gX = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(function(d) {
        return formatTime(d)
      }).tickValues(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.Date
      })))
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)")
      .attr("y", 4)
      .attr("x", -10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

    var gY = svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

    var valueOneLine = svg.append("path")
      .datum(valueOneData)
      .attr("d", lineGenerator)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "#124");

    var valueTwoLine = svg.append("path")
      .datum(valueTwoData)
      .attr("d", lineGenerator)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "#c7003b");

  //RESPONSIVENESS ATTEMPT NO1
  d3.select(window).on("resize", resized);

}

//Resize function
function resized() {
    d3.select("svg").remove();
    set_vars();
    drawGraphic();
    console.log("FUNCTION IS BEING CALLED")
}

set_vars();
drawGraphic();

 //RESPONSIVENESS ATTEMPT NO2
 window.addEventListener("resize", function(){ d3.select("svg").remove(); set_vars(); drawGraphic(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="charts"></div>
```

In the snippet, I have tried two ways to do that. None of them make the chart recreate from scratch. The same issue applied in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Templates/5j49a6ty/).

Comment: Do you check the console errors by any chance?

Comment: I got no errors.

Comment: Is it? That's weird. Anyway posting the answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the parsing of the data every time the window was resized.

As the **date** within the data is parsed the first time, calling `parseDate(d.date)` will fail on every other call as it's already been parsed to a valid date. Do you get it?

Hence, moving the parsing code so that it's executed just once:

```
// parse data just once
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.value = +d.value;
});
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/a5rqt0L1/

**Suggestion:** I feel this isn't the right way to make a responsive chart i.e. removing SVG and re-appending to the body with all the configuration done multiple times. Here's how I'd do it:

1. Parse the data, append svg with initial height and width, append X, Y axes *just once* but move `drawBars` (to draw the actual bars) to a separate function that will use d3's own **enter, exit and update** selection logic.
2. On window resize, just change the SVG's height and width, re-render the axes by `.call(xAxis)...` and just call the `drawBars` function.

Hope this helps.